# No '(closed)' in titles in RSS feed

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, feed

Hi all!

When I view this RSS feed: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds
it does not show me whether a question is already closed or migrated (if it should :) ). So if I want to say, close a question I must first open my web browser, then open the page and then notice 'oh, it is already closed' and that costs much valuable time.

Comment: The problem is that you can't edit the "past" (feed).

Comment: I update my SO feeds every minute since it's updated very frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was a regression; I added it back in.